# HP Quality Center retrieve data from DB

Tags: vbscript, hp-quality-center

I'm running a few vb scripts on my QC server using the script editor.
I'm using QC 12, i have a function that is establishing a connection using QC api, getting some data then incrementing this data by one, the thing is that it's getting an empty value from the DB.
Here is the function:

```
Function SW_KeepTIDLastValue()
On Error Resume Next
  Dim tdc, val
  Dim cset
  Dim bld
  On Error Resume Next
  bld = ""
  Set tdc = TDConnection     'Open a connection using the QC API
  Set tdc =  CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
  Set cset = tdc.CommonSettings
  'Set cset = tdc.COMMON_SETTINGS
    cset.Open ("KeepTIDValueSetting")
    val = cset.Value("KeepTIDValueField")   'Retrieve the value stored in the DB
   ' val = CDbl(cset.Value("KeepTIDValueField"))
    msgbox(TypeName(val) & " " & val)
    SW_KeepTIDLastValue = val+1             'Increment the value by 1
    msgbox(TypeName(val) & " " & SW_KeepTIDLastValue )
    cset.Value("KeepTIDValueField") = val+1 'Store the value back in the DB
    cset.Close

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  SW_DisplayError Err.Number, Err.Description, "Keep Last Value (" & action & ")"
End If

On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Get rid of your TWO `On Error Resume Next` statements and try your code again. It's going to be difficult to find the issue when you're purposefully hiding errors.

Comment: I've removed it, but it's not going through the function

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, it's just not doing anything, i have a messageboxes for debugging, and they're not popping up

Comment: Where is this function called ? If the message boxes don't apper it is because your function is never called. Another problem is that you create tdconnection two times by using two different techniques. The second message box doesn't appear because you return to the function with this line of code "SW_KeepTIDLastValue = val+1 "